# Distributive generators of a lattice

Tags: co.combinatorics, lattice-theory

Given a finite lattice $L$, suppose $L$ is generated by a set $X$ such that the distributive law holds for all $a,b,c\in X$ i.e. $a\lor (b \wedge c) = (a\lor b)\wedge (a \lor c)$.

Is $L$ distributive?

Comment: Does Lemma 2 in [Gein, A. G., & Shushpanov, M. P. (2017), *Modularity and Distributivity of 3-Generated Lattices with Special Elements Among Generators*, Algebra and Logic, 56(1), 1–12. doi:10.1007/s10469-017-9423-z](http://sci-hub.tw/https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s10469-017-9423-z.pdf) disprove your conjecture, or am I getting something wrong about the meanings of the words involved?

Comment: See Bjarni Jónsson, "Distributive Sublattices of a Modular Lattice,"
Proceedings of the American Mathematical Society
Vol. 6, No. 5 (Oct., 1955), pp. 682-688